# iTerm2 installed from MacPorts fails to start with "not valid for use in process: mapped file has no Team ID"

Tags: mac, macports, osx-ventura

Installed iTerm2 with MacPorts, as it is described in the packages' documentation.

When trying to start the application it fails with the following error

```
% /Applications/MacPorts/iTerm2.app/Contents/MacOS/iTerm2 
dyld[23279]: Library not loaded: @rpath/BetterFontPicker.framework/Versions/A/BetterFontPicker
  Referenced from: <E578C903-50EB-3B2F-BEC3-FE121AE39446> /Applications/MacPorts/iTerm2.app/Contents/MacOS/iTerm2
  Reason: tried: '/Applications/MacPorts/iTerm2.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/BetterFontPicker.framework/Versions/A/BetterFontPicker' (code signature in <ED4B4372-9E02-37AE-ADED-0A904093467D> '/Applications/MacPorts/iTerm2.app/Contents/Frameworks/BetterFontPicker.framework/Versions/A/BetterFontPicker' not valid for use in process: mapped file has no Team ID and is not a platform binary (signed with custom identity or adhoc?)), '/Applications/MacPorts/iTerm2.app/Contents/Frameworks/BetterFontPicker.framework/Versions/A/BetterFontPicker' (code signature in <ED4B4372-9E02-37AE-ADED-0A904093467D> '/Applications/MacPorts/iTerm2.app/Contents/Frameworks/BetterFontPicker.framework/Versions/A/BetterFontPicker' not valid for use in process: mapped file has no Team ID and is not a platform binary (signed with custom identity or adhoc?)), '/Applications/MacPorts/iTerm2.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/BetterFontPicker.framework/Versions/A/BetterFontPicker' (code signature in <ED4B4372-9E02-37AE-ADED-0A904093467D> '/Applications/MacPorts/iTerm2.app/Contents/Frameworks/BetterFontPicker.framework/Versions/A/BetterFontPicker' not valid for use in process: mapped file has no Team ID and is not a platform binary (signed with custom identity or adhoc?)), '/Applications/MacPorts/iTerm2.app/Contents/Frameworks/BetterFontPicker.framework/Versions/A/BetterFontPicker' (code signature in <ED4B4372-9E02-37AE-ADED-0A904093467D> '/Applications/MacPorts/iTerm2.app/Contents/Frameworks/BetterFontPicker.framework/Versions/A/BetterFontPicker' not valid for use in process: mapped file has no Team ID and is not a platform binary (signed with custom identity or adhoc?)), '/System/Library/Frameworks/BetterFontPicker.framework/Versions/A/BetterFontPicker' (no such file, not in dyld cache)
zsh: abort      /Applications/MacPorts/iTerm2.app/Contents/MacOS/iTerm2
```

System details:

```
% uname -a
Darwin iMac.local 22.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 22.5.0: Mon Apr 24 20:51:50 PDT 2023; root:xnu-8796.121.2~5/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

% port version
Version: 2.8.1

% codesign -v -d /Applications/MacPorts/iTerm2.app/Contents/MacOS/iTerm2 
Executable=/Applications/MacPorts/iTerm2.app/Contents/MacOS/iTerm2
Identifier=com.googlecode.iterm2
Format=app bundle with Mach-O universal (x86_64 arm64)
CodeDirectory v=20500 size=144086 flags=0x10002(adhoc,runtime) hashes=4492+7 location=embedded
Signature=adhoc
Info.plist=not bound
TeamIdentifier=not set
Runtime Version=13.0.0
Sealed Resources version=2 rules=13 files=320
Internal requirements count=0 size=12
```

My guess is that the culprit will be the `Signature=adhoc`. Any ideas how to solve it?

I tried to uninstall and reinstall the port, that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

This is discussed in the post
[iTerm 2 crashes on startup](https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/-/issues/10728).

The problem is said to be that `TeamIdentifier` is not set.

The final opinion was :

> sounds like a macports problem. Please report it to them!

I would suggest to contact
[MacPorts Support](https://www.macports.org/contact.php)
about the problem, or try to find an older version that doesn't have
this problem.